# reading with pread() and writing with pwrite() in c

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

My program(below) writes(with **pwrite()**) text to a file and reads(with **pread()**) from the file. My problems are pread function doesn't read my text from file and what's wrong with close function(last part of program)? Results is in the second part. Where is my mistake?

```
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    int main()
    {

        int fd, nr, nr2, nw, nw2;
        char fl_nm[]={"file_io/pwrite.txt"};
        char buf_wr[]={"hello everyone this is first text\n"};
        char buf_wr2[]={"Did you miss me? Don't afraid\n"};
        char buf_rd[120];
        char buf_rd2[120];

        //open file
        fd = open(fl_nm, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0777);
        nw = pwrite(fd, &buf_wr, strlen(buf_wr), 14);

        //error checking
        if(fd == -1){
            perror("[error in open]\n");
        }
        else if(nw == -1){
            perror("[error in write]\n");
        }
        else{

            /*if open and write process are okey, read first write data
            * from file*/
            nr = read(fd, &buf_rd, sizeof(buf_rd));

            //display succeeded message about first write and open process
            printf("[file is opened]\n");
            printf("[succeeded write(1) process]\n");

            //read process error control
            if(nr == -1){
                perror("[error in read]\n");
            } else{
            printf("[reading(1) data] from %s\n", fl_nm);
            printf("[%s]\n", buf_rd);
            }

        }

        //second write process.
        nw2= pwrite(fd, &buf_wr2, strlen(buf_wr2), 30);

        //write error checking
        if(nw2 == -1){
            perror("[error in write 2]\n");
        }else{

            /*if write process is correct
            * second read process*/
            nr2 = read(fd, &buf_rd2, sizeof(buf_rd));

            printf("-----------------------------------\n");
            printf("[succeeded write(2) process]\n");
            printf("[reading(2) data] from %s\n", fl_nm);
            printf("[%s]\n", buf_rd2);
        }

        //close file
        close(fd);

        //error checking for close process
        if(close(fd) == -1){
            perror("[error in close]\n");
        }else{
            printf("[succeeded in close]\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Result:

```
$ gcc pwrite.c -o pwrite
$ ./pwrite
[file is opened]
[succeeded write(1) process]
[reading(1) data] from file_io/pwrite.txt
[]
-----------------------------------
[succeeded write(2) process]
[reading(2) data] from file_io/pwrite.txt
[]
[error in close]
: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Per [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), `read()`, `pread()`, `write()` and `pwrite()` return `ssize_t`, not `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `close()` fails because you are closing the file *twice*:

```
//close file
close(fd);

//error check close process
if(close(fd) == -1){
```

After the first call to `close(fd);`, `fd` becomes indeterminate and the second call to `close(fd)` fails. You just need to remove the first call to `close(fd);`.

2) You are printing `buf_rd` as if it's a C-string. `read()` doesn't terminate `buf_rd` with a null byte.

3) You are writing at random offsets (14 and 30) using `pwrite()`. But `read()` reads from current offset - which means the starting byte could a null byte and thus `%s` stops printing right away (i.e. prints nothing). You are reading a lot more than what you write. That means `read()` is going to return less than the requested number of bytes. So use the return value of `read()` to get the number of bytes successfully read.

Instead, print each byte using a loop:

```
 for (size_t l = 0; l < nr; l++)
    printf("%c", buf_rd[l]);
```

and

```
 for (size_t l = 0; l < nr2; l++)
    printf("%c", buf_rd2[l]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using pointers incorrectly, accessing to address of arrays should be with their names alone, not &name.

replace &buf_wr with buf_wr, accessing to incorrect address with &buf_wr to writing there will corrupt your stack and also variables defined inside stack

**Edit:**

replace

```
nw = pwrite(fd, &buf_wr, strlen(buf_wr), 14);
```

to

```
nw = pwrite(fd, buf_wr, strlen(buf_wr), 14);
```

and all other instances..

Comment: Output didn't changed. It still same result.

Comment: did you replaced all instances? edit your post and put edited code

Comment: This should not matter. I am not saying that the change from `&buf_wr` to `buf_wr` is wrong, but that this argument is of type `(const void *)` in the function prototype; both of the above expressions will lead to the same function call after the type conversion.